# Trying to read a file + print to stdout in shellcode

Tags: shellcode

I'm able to open + read the file, but can't seem to get the call to `sys_write` just right... ??

```
<< Redacted until the end of the challenge >>
```

The [beginning of] the file contents gets to stdout, but the content leads me to believe it's truncated (ends mid-word and continues as garbage) after ~105 bytes...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So turns out I just needed to pass [a longer] `rdx` to sys_read (and adjust the sys_write command accordingly!